# Can I rewrite the sentence with 'are'?

Tags: grammaticality

I read a sentence in a book. In the sentence, 'you' and 'is' have been used together. Can I rewrite it with 'are'?

> The real you is inside of you.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, because here the "is" is used together with "the real you", which is not the same as just the pronoun "you". "The real you" is a synonym for "your real self" or "your real personality" among others. That is why, "is" is used and not "are".

Comment: Perhaps if the person had multiple personalities . . . (in which case it would be *the real yous are inside of you*) but it would take an unusual context like that. It's not something that would normally be considered.